# Update in firestore not working as intended

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, updates

I am setting a update function where every time user clicks button there is decrement of one in field in firestore.....but the problem is it doesn't just stop at when it keeps derementing till value reaches zero

```
final String di=getIntent().getStringExtra("DocumentID");
DocumentReference dref=db.collection("User").document(di);
Toast.makeText(managersAction.this," "+di+" "+j,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
dref.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onEvent(
@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot,            
@Nullable F  irebaseFirestoreException e) {
    String space=documentSnapshot.getString("Space");
    int s=Integer.parseInt(space);
    if(s==0){
        AlertDialog.Builder x=
 new AlertDialog.Builder( managersAction.this);
        x.setMessage("Not Allowed")
  .setPositiveButton (android.R.string.ok,null);
        AlertDialog v=x.create();
        v.show();
    }
    else{
        int newspace = s - 1;
        final String sp = Integer.toString(newspace);

   Toast.makeText(mnagersAction.this, " "+sp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show   ();
        DocumentReference dref=db.collection("User").document(di);
        dref.update("Space",sp);
                return;
    }
return;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below code from the listener:

```
DocumentReference dref=db.collection("User").document(di);
dref.update("Space",sp);
```

As event listener will be called every time when there is a change in db.